# System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute'

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I have using `.net core 3.1` to update the model from existing database.

Try to add entity using below comment in package manager console,

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=xxxxxxxx;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --output-dir UserEntity --table users
```

Got the below exception,

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(MetadataToken caCtorToken, MetadataImport& scope, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1& derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1& attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute[T](Assembly element)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.ConfigureProviderServices(String provider, IServiceCollection services, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.Build(String provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

**Note :**

Using the below entity version,

1. `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design - 3.1.6`
2. `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer - 1.1.6`

> Could any one help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are using older version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`? Try updating it to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.1.6`.

As I searched for the error it looks like `DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute` was only supported till `Entity Framework Core 1.1` which was under `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure`.

As you are using newer versions `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure` does not include `DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute`. Verify same on MSDN here

- [DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute efcore-1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure?view=efcore-1.1)
- [DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute efcore-3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure?view=efcore-3.1).